# How to wait between PostgreSQL DB restore and reindexing?

Tags: postgresql, restore

I've written a [script](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27033/how-to-wait-for-postgresql-to-be-startable-restorable) to upgrade PostgreSQL from 8.2.1 to 9.2.1 on a Linux From Scratch distribution:

1. Start the `pg` service
2. Vacuum all DBs (not sure if this is needed)
3. Backup with `pg_dumpall`
4. Stop the `pg` service
5. Move away the directory where the data is stored (`/var/pg`; it's a simple, single-server setup)
6. Install PostgreSQL 9.2.1
7. `initdb`
8. Start the server
9. Restore the dumped data
10. [`reindexdb` all DBs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/release-8-3-5.html)
11. Recreate the `referential_constraints` view
12. Vacuum all DBs (AFAIK required after this upgrade)

Unfortunately reindexing fails in about one third of the executions, even when using a virtual machine which I reset between tries. The code:

```
PGOPTIONS='--client-min-messages=warning' psql \
    --no-psqlrc \
    --variable=ON_ERROR_STOP=1 \
    --quiet \
    --log-file="$restore_log" \
    --single-transaction \
    --username postgres \
    --file="$sql_backup"
[error checking which stops the script if the import failed]
for database in $(databases); do
    reindexdb --username postgres $database
    [error checking which stops the script if the reindex failed]
done
```

The restore log shows no error at the end. The last lines of the `reindexdb` output (anonymized to be able to publish it):

```
NOTICE:  table "myschema.mytable" was reindexed
reindexdb: reindexing of database "myschema" failed: ERROR:  could not open relation with OID 16738
```

`/var/log/pg/postmasterlog` contents during the upgrade:

After a VM reset I found that the OID belongs to a table which is backed up and restored properly. Could it be a problem that the `reindexdb` step is run immediately after `psql` has processed the backup file?

Edit: This is getting even worse - This time I encountered another issue I haven't seen before:

```
reindexdb: reindexing of database "myschema" failed: ERROR:  deadlock detected
DETAIL:  Process 3883 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 17684 of database 16385; blocked by process 3980.
Process 3980 waits for RowExclusiveLock on relation 16513 of database 16385; blocked by process 3883.
```

In `/var/log/messages`:

```
Process 3980: UPDATE tablename SET [...]
```

Looks like **the problem is a cron job which was trying to update the database during the reindexing.**

Comment: That shouldn't happen, something dodgy's going on here.  Once `psql` finishes running a script to restore the DB and commits, it should be ready for use. Is this reindex running on 8.2.23? Or are you dumping and reloading, then running the reindex on 9.2? If so, 9.2.what and on what platform? Is there anything informative in the server logs between the end of the restore and the reindexdb run?

Comment: Also: Was the dump created with 9.2's `pg_dump`, or 8.2's? What happens if you insert `psql postgres -c 'CHECKPOINT;'` between the end of the restore and the start of the `reindexdb` loop? Are you using any GiST or GIN indexes? Finally, can you reproduce this issue by restoring a dump file that you're able to publish/distribute, or is it specific to this one dump from your old system?

Comment: Note that the `REINDEX` step only applies if you're updating an 8.3.x cluster in-place from x<5 to x>=5. It does *not* apply for dump and restore. You do not need to perform this step. You won't even be using 8.3, you'll be going straight from 8.2 to 9.2 (right?). That said, this *really* shouldn't be happening, so more info as requested.

Comment: Oh, and when you say `reindexing of database "myschema" failed` - is that just a search and replace error where you concealed the real DB and schema names?

Comment: Updated as far as I can from your suggestions - I'll add more info if I manage to reproduce the problem soon. If you make your third comment an answer, then I can accept it. Unfortunately I can't promise to work much longer on this.

Comment: Er. Linux from Scratch tends to mean "potentially subtly broken", so unless the issue can be reproduced on a stable distro it's going to be hard to get much interest in it.

Comment: @CraigRinger It is a stable distro (used on many servers), just not available to the public. But yes, it's a problem asking meaningful questions with so much special context.

Comment: Thanks for following up to confirm the root cause of the issue. Naughty cron job, no cookie. Still interesting that it managed to jag some kind of race with reindex, though ... might have to put a sandbox together and see if I can reproduce that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the `REINDEX` step only applies if you're updating an 8.3.x cluster in-place from x<5 to x>=5. It does not apply for dump and restore. You do not need to perform this step for what you are doing. You won't even be using 8.3, you'll be going straight from 8.2 to 9.2 (right?).

Also, as per the upgrade documentation, you should use the *new* PostgreSQL's `pg_dump` when preparing for an upgrade, not the *old* version.

That said, this really shouldn't be happening; see comments.